# Is this a real contradiction? Where is the mistake?

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers, solution-verification

If $a \cdot b=0$, then either $a=0$ or $b=0$.

```
Proof:
```

Assume $a\neq 0$, we prove $b=0$.

$ a = a \cdot 1 = a (b(1/b)) = a \cdot b (1/b) = 0 (1/b) = 0 $

Since we assumed $a \neq 0 $, isn't this a contradiction? Where is the mistake?

Comment: In writing $1$ as $b(1/b)$, you have assumed $b\neq 0$.

Comment: $\frac{1}{b}=\frac{1}{0}$

Comment: What if $a=5$ and $b=0$.  You havent proven (and can't prove because it isn't true) that it must be $a$ that is $0$.  And you can't prove that $a$ *isn't* $0$ and your contradiction should actually contradict anything because $a$ doesn't *have* to be $0$.  ... It not clear in your argument of using $ab\frac 1b$ if you were actually intending to assume $b\ne 0$ and get a c contradiction.

Comment: tl;dr the contradiction isn't that $a \ne 0$.  It's that $b\ne $.  ... I think to fix your prove it'd be:  Assume $a\ne 0$ so divide by $a$, not $b$, you *can't* divide by $b$ because $b$ *might* be $0$.  So $ab =0$ and $a\ne 0$ then $\frac 1aab = b = \frac 1a 0 = 0$.  So if $a\ne 0$ then $b=0$.  ANd if $a=0$ ... then $a = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is you wish to prove b = 0, but you inverted b, so you are assuming b is not 0.

Comment: Your idea is almost correct. I will assume here that the if a number is not zero then  you can invert it.So suppose ab = 0. Assume a is not zero. Then a^(-1)ab = 0 . Thus b= 0 since a*a^(-1) = 1.

Answer (score 0):

You got a contradiction because you assumed both $a,b$ are nonzero but $a.b=0!$